# How to properly import sub-modules in a Python package?

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I am a bit lost about how I should import and organise my sub-modules and I need some literature and some conventions.

### The problem

We want to write a new package written in Python that is composed of several components:

- Classes and functions useful for the end user
- Classes and functions rarely used
- Utilities classes and functions only needed by the package itself
- External modules

We consider this architecture:

```
pizzafactory
├── __init__.py
├── salt.py 
├── water.py 
├── vegetables
│   ├── __init__.py 
│   └── tomatoes.py 
└── dough
    ├── __init__.py 
    └── flour.py
```

### Some considerations

- The end user don't need to use raw ingredients such as dough or water
- The customer only need pizzas described in `pizzafactory/__init__.py`
- The dough factory requires salt and water
- The customer may want to add some tomatoes on its pizza.

The file `pizzafactory/__init__.py` needs almost all the modules, but because we don't want to pollute the end user namespace with useless things. I would propose to import the ingredients quietly except for those that may be used by the customer:

```
# pizzafactory/__init__.py
import salt as _salt
import dough as _dough
import vegetables.tomatoes

import oven as _oven # External package
```

The dough factory will require some water, but the user who need to use that sub-module (to make bread), may don't want to see the `water`.

```
# pizzafactory/dough/__init__.py
import pizzafactory.water as _water
```

### Discussion

First, I feel it's always easier to directly import everything either the full package:

```
import pizzafactory

def grab_tomato():
    return pizzafactory.vegetables.tomatoes.BeefsteakTomato()
```

or only the required elements:

```
from pizzafactory.vegetables.tomatoes import BeefsteakTomato

def grab_tomato():
    return BeefsteakTomato()
```

Both of these methods are common, but it may pollute the `pizzafactory` namespace, so it may be preferable to mangle the import names. I relalized that nobody does that and I don't know why.

### Question

In this generic example, I would like to know how to properly import modules,  sub-modules and external packages in order to:

- Minimize the namespace footprint
- Help the end user to clearly see only what he is intended to used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both of these methods are common, but it may pollute the pizzafactory namespace, so it may be preferable to mangle the import names. I relalized that nobody does that and I don't know why.

Python is a consenting adult language, we leave the doors unlocked and everything out in the open, for the most part.

If you're concern is just crowding the namespaces, you should define `__all__` as well as use single-leading underscores. -- PEP8 suggests that name mangling should only be used to avoid naming clashes, so that's probably why nobody does that.

See the [Public and internal interfaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces) section of PEP8 as well as [Naming Convensions.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

PEP8 is the guide for the "proper" way to do these kinds of things. Though, it is a *guide* not necessarily *law*. You have the flexibility to do what you feel is appropriate for your package, which leads to my favorite section of PEP8 - [A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)

Without being sufficiently intimate with the code in a package, one probably could not offer much advice beyond PEP8 on how it *should* be done. If you have the time, Raymond Hettinger's talk [Beyond PEP 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M) is a worthwhile watch.